# Issue when using Polymer through HtmlService in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-apps-script, polymer

I just noticed that a code that worked before in Firefox is throwing errors now

This is a simple Google Apps Script sample code (embedded in a Google spreadsheet) to reproduce the issue:

server side:

```
function uiTest(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ui-test');
  var ui = html.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui," ");
}
```

where ui-test html:

```
<head>
  <base href="//polygit.org/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-material/paper-material.html">

  <dom-module id="ui-firefox">
    <template>
      <paper-material>Can you see me in Firefox?</paper-material>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: "ui-firefox",
          ready: function() {
            console.log("Am I ready?");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</head>

<body>
  <ui-firefox> </ui-firefox>
</body>
```

The error is as follow ...

The resource from “https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://n-47juae2agfc3xqpt4fvdar7apw5jvvjx5nohrjy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js&followup=https://n-47juae2agfc3xqpt4fvdar7apw5jvvjx5nohrjy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Any ideas on how to fix/avoid this issue?
﻿

Comment: Is there a reason you are set-origin:allowall when using inside a spreadsheet?

Comment: @SpencerEaston no reason, I was just trying it and let it there, no change if removed -- thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the Firefox release 58 from Jan.23, 2018 this is issue is gone, no longer happening.
Hopefully it'd stay that way ...